# how to pass output of a stored procedure , as input to file system task in ssis to move a file

Tags: sql-server, file, ssis, task

i need to move files abcd.txt , ijk.txt from C:\files to their respective folders C:\moved_files\abcd\abcd.txt  and  C:\moved_files\ijk\ijk.txt ,  where the file name and destination folder name should be same , the folders already exist ;

i have the following stored procedure in sql server database which returns the folder name when provided with filename as the input ,

i have put this stored procedure in execute sql task of SSIS , i now want the output of this stored procedure i.e the foldername , should be taken as destination variable by the file system task to move files to respective folder.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[FOLDER]
( 
@CSVFILENAME AS VARCHAR(600)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Index AS INT
DECLARE @FOLDER AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @CSVFILE AS VARCHAR(500)

SET @CSVFILENAME = REPLACE(UPPER(@CSVFILENAME),'\\dm2nas1\U\sql_data\in\','')
SET @CSVFILE = @CSVFILENAME

SET @CSVFILENAME = REPLACE(UPPER(@CSVFILENAME),'.csv','')
SET @Index = CHARINDEX('_',@CSVFILENAME)

IF @CSVFILENAME LIKE '%TRACKER%'
SET @FOLDER = 'TRACKER'
ELSE
SET @FOLDER = SUBSTRING(@CSVFILENAME,@Index + 1,LEN(@CSVFILENAME))
SELECT @FOLDER
END
```

I have for each loop container with execute sql task and file system task , and two variables user::filename and user::destfolder. i want the output of the stored procedure i.e the foldername to be stored in variable user::destfolder , which can then be given in the destination variable value in the file system task 
Can someone please help me with the variable mapping such that files are moved to destination folder based on output of the stored procedure.

Comment: I have no experience with SSIS, but maybe output variables could do the trick?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to put the folder derivation logic into SSIS rather than SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you stick the results of the stored procedure (via `SQL Execute Task`) into an (ADO?) object variable. This will act as a DataTable or DataSet (depending on what you return from the `Execute SQL task`) and the columns return can be mapped to variables if you use a Foreach loop container.

### Here the step by step instructions

You need to amend your stored procedure so it returns the two  values you want filename and destfolder. Also remember the column  order i.e. `SELECT @CSVFILE, @FOLDER`

1. Create an object variable (User::objResults).
2. Create an `Execute SQL Task`

   - In General tab

     1. Add the name of the stored procedure
     2. Set ResultSet (single row or full resultset)
   - In the Result Set tab

     1. Add new item ResultName is 0
     2. Set VariableName as User::objResults
3. Attach your `Foreach Loop Container` to the end of the `` `Execute SQL Task `` and set the enumerator as ADO Enumerator.

Comment: the basic purpose of my package is to move files from one folder to another based on the folder name matching the file name , the for each loop contaions the execute sql task and flie system task , the for each loop has the variable user::filename , i want to pass the value in this variable as input to the stored procedure , and the output of stored procedure to be stored in user::destfolder , the file system task should make use of this user::destfolder n move files

Comment: settings in file system task editor areas below
IsDestinationPathVariable : True
 
DestinationVariable : User::desfolder

operation: move file

IsSourcePathVariable: False

SourceConnection: inputfile

Comment: Ah, I think I get what you want. You have an existing For Each Loop container, inside this you want to have an Execute SQL (on your stored proc) and then do a move using File System Task? Let me know if I've understood the problem and I'll rewrite the answer.